# Android Parse database query

Tags: android, database, parse-platform

I have a Parse table with columns in the DB as username,email and address. When the user signs in, I want to check if the user has filled in the address or not. How do I query the DB for a  particular username and check if the address column is null or not?

I am writing data into the table s below.

```
final ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("UserDetails");
testObject.put("UserName", userName);
testObject.put("Email", EmailStr);

testObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

@Override
public void done(com.parse.ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (e == null) {
        // Success!
     objectId = testObject.getObjectId().toString();

    } else {
        // Failure!
            }
            }
    });
```

This wrighting will happen when the users signs up. after sign up, when the user logs in, I want to edit some of the data in the UserDetails table for that particular user. Like I want to check if the Address column for the user is blank of full. if it is blank I want to enforce the user to fill it. This is just on example. In general, I want to know a way In which I can modify certain columns of a particular row.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("UserDetails");
query.whereEqualTo("UserName", username);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> arg0,
                com.parse.ParseException arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (arg1 == null) {

                userExistance = true;
                if (arg0.size() == 1)
                    Tv1.setText(username + " exists in UserDeatils DB too");
                else if (arg0.size() > 1)
                    Tv1.setText(username
                            + " exists in UserDeatils DB multiple times");
                else
                    Tv1.setText(username
                            + " does not exist in UserDeatils DB");

            } else {
                Log.d("score", "Error: " + arg1.getMessage());
            }

        }
    });
```

I have implemented the above code t check if the users exists in the UserDetails table or not, after loging in. Now I wan to check the address column of this user in the UserDetails class.

Comment: You really need to show [what you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).....

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to add the code earlier, I have added it now. Please give me your inputs

Answer (score 0):

For the UserDetails, find the username. Then for the particular username check the ContactAddress column

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("UserDetails");
query.whereEqualTo("UserName", username);

query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> arg0,
                com.parse.ParseException arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (arg1 == null) {

                ParseObject p = arg0.get(0);
                if(p.getString("ContactAddress")==null)
                    {
                       p.put("ContactAddress",address + " " +city +" " +state +" " +country);
                       p.saveInBackground();
                    }
            }
            else {
                Log.d("score", "Error: " + arg1.getMessage());
            }
       }
});
```